# Load URL from a tuple of URL's

Tags: xcode, web, swift2, tuples, nsurl

I have a large list of URL's in a tuple and when I press a button and it randomly selects a URL and then push a second button to loads the URL.  Pushing the first button again would just switch to another URL for the second button to load.  I got the random part to work so I just need to know how to pass a URL from my list into a button tap. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

I'm doing something like this right now but instead of loading a specific site like yahoo.com(like I did here) I want one of my randomly selected sites to be loaded

```
@IBAction func ButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    let url = NSURL(string:"http://www.yahoo.com")!
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)

    webView.loadRequest(request)
}
```

Comment: Had you even test the code?

Answer (score 0):

If you got your random part done, you can just declare an array of URL you want.

```
let arrURL = NSMutableArray()
arrURL.addObject("http://www.yahoo.com")
arrURL.addObject("http://www.google.com")
arrURL.addObject("http://www.youtube.com")
....
```

Then when your button was tapped, generate a random number inside and use array for your URL like

```
let position = N//RANDOM NUMBER YOU HAD DONE
let url = NSURL(string: arrURL[position] as! String)
//continue the rest
.....
```

UPDATE:

If you mean click first button to randomly generate a number, then save the number in a variable

Then when you click the second button, get the array of URL at position u saved in first button `arrURL[position] as! String` then just load it in webView